# Setting view with ConstraintSet

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with ConstraintSet property, I had constraint layout done and I wanted it to change some constraints by code, but when i created new ConstraintLayout and set context to "this" and then setContentView(myLayout) it is a blank space. How to make it show layout that I've made earlier?

onCreate()

```
      @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ConstraintLayout myLayout = new ConstraintLayout(this);
    setContentView(myLayout);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gr);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

Comment: The ConstraintLayout that you create is completely empty, and also after you set it, you override it by setting the layout to the xml layout called activity_gr.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to inflate the constraintLayout you have made in an xml normally just do:

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_gr);
```

without anything else.

If you want to mess about with ConstraintSets and stuff programatically it can be done like this:

```
ConstraintLayout myLayout = new ConstraintLayout(this);
ConstraintSet constraints = new ConstraintSet();
constraints.clone(context, R.layout.activity_gr);
myLayout.setConstraintSet(constraints);
setContentView(myLayout);
```

Under the hood in the `clone()`-call the layout is inflated. Keep in mind this only keeps the constraint part of the layout.

And then you can programatically add constraints like:

```
constraints.connect(R.id.some_id, TOP, R.id.some_other_id, BOTTOM)
```

If I interpret your questions correctly I think you should set and id on your contraintLayout in the xml like `my_container` and do:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_gr);
ConstraintLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.my_container)
ConstraintSet constraints = new ConstraintSet();
constraints.clone(layout);
// Edit constraints of the constraints set
// Apply your new constraints to the inflated layout
constraints.applyTo(layout)
```